# Are interactive features actually an aspect of graphic design, or are they strictly a UX topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, critique

I design user interfaces, and dynamic change via user interactivity is, to me, the most important aspect of my graphic design.

I design straight into the browser. I'm more comfortable building my designs with CSS than I am in doing it with Photoshop, and as a result, interactivity has become, to me, part of the graphic design of the interface.

Since we can't embed video to demonstrate that, any critique I request of my interface designs here will only be able to take into account the static features of the interface's design.

**Are interactive features actually an aspect of graphic design, or are they strictly a UX topic?**

Comment: Something else about this I'm interested in is whether or not there is an SE movement towards adding youtube video embeds to the site.

Comment: Some sites do have video embedding enabled ([example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53915/13206))

Comment: @JohnB oh cool. I wish it were enabled here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases that are hard to call, think about the best way to illustrate your question's subject:

- If using a Balsamq-style wireframe would be fine for the question, then UX.SE
- If that would lose something about the design that is important to the question, then here

---

As for the question about **how to include samples of something interactive**: I'd suggest linking to a demo in something like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/) for a real interactive demo. Since it's the result not the code that is of interest, link to the full screen view e.g. [this](http://jsbin.com/hegihuki/2/) not [this](http://jsbin.com/hegihuki/2/edit).

Options if you don't like the idea of hosting project code on a 3rd party site:

- Host it yourself and link direct or iframe it
- For Javascript, running it through a minifier e.g. [Google Closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) might help (but don't rely on this as a way of securing the code!)

Answer (score 3):

Is it a question about how the user interacts with said feature? Then its UX

Is it a question about the design of said feature? Then its GD

Comment: It's sort of in-between, the way I see it. My question is about the design, but the design cannot be fully appreciated without user interactivity, as many important aspects of the interactive design are only visible or apparent via user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic Design is always a part of the User Experience.

Graphic Designers are often User Experience and Interaction Designers.

Interaction Design has to integrate well with the Graphic Design.

But I'd say no, interaction design questions in and of themselves are giong to (typically) be a better fit for UX.se rather than GD.se